# NotImplementedException when calling delegate

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

I am implementing an event structure to pass information from a View to a Presenter. In the view, the following code is called when a button is clicked:

```
private void alterCmpd1()
{
    EventHandler AlterEvent = AlterCompound1_Action;
    if (AlterEvent != null) AlterEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

public event EventHandler AlterCompound1_Action;
```

For some reason, a NotImplementedException always appears on:

```
AlertEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Could someone help me figure out why?

Code from Presenter class:

```
    public MainPresenter(IMainView view, IModel model)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.view.AlterCompound1_Action += new EventHandler(view_AlterCompound1);
        this.model = model;
        view.Show();
    }

    void view_AlterCompound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // I commented out this code, on the off
        // chance that it was affecting things. Still no luck.
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Will, I realized the mistake I was making. I had been using the "Build Solution" tool, but I neglected to look in the Build Configuration Manager for Visual Studio 2010 (Build -> Configuration Manager). There, I found this:

[image: Screenshot of configuration manager in VS2010]

Before, some of those Build column check marks (corresponding to the projects that I was editing, such as QAz.Presenter and QAz.View) were not selected, so "Build Solution" was skipping over them. After those projects were selected, Visual Studio knew to build them when I ran the solution.

Answer (score 5):

90% sure if you look you'll find this.

```
private void AlterCompound1_Action(object, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That would've made my life easier.

Comment: @QtotheC: I bet if you deleted the MainPresenter class, recompiled and ran the exception would happen anyhow.  Try it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thought that it would complain about missing a class somewhere else. What's causing it? Does it have anything to do with my code files being split among different classes? I'm working in VS 2010 and telling it to Rebuild Solution.

Comment: Thanks to your comment, I realized that the issue results from improperly building the solution. I had been accustomed to hitting "Rebuild Solution" in Visual Studio, but it appears that I need to individually build the projects to catch some mistakes. I don't have enough reputation to self-answer my question, but this is my conclusion.

Comment: @QtotheC The problem is that you aren't using solution references.  You must have added a reference by browsing to the bin folder.  Remove all references among projects in your solution and re-add them as project references http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx this will ensure your solution projects properly reference each other, and that the solution knows the dependencies of one project on another so that builds are performed in the correct order.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et61xzb3.aspx